# How to make standalone after linking Qt Statically?

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator, qt5

I think I've rebuilt Qt statically (ran this line `configure -static -nomake examples -qt-sql-mysql -I C:\MySql\include -L C:\MySql\lib`) and then `mingw32-make`. It didn't give me any errors. What is next? I am using Qt5.1.0

Comment: Build your application?

Comment: Idk what I use to "build" (location of the static qt). I'm the the brightest person on the block

Comment: Idk where the static qt I use to build is is what im trying to say

Comment: add CONFIG += static to your .pro file. Use QT\mkspecs\mingw32\qmake.conf edited to static builds

Comment: @SebastianLange I don't get what you mean by the second part "Use Qt\...\qmake.conf edited to static builds"

Comment: in your %QTDIR%, the directory your QT Framework is installed, there are build specifications under the directory mkspecs. Given your needs you may need to change them. Try building a small app an run it in a non-development environment not having QT installed, then you will see if your app is compiled static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the static Qt version into Creator's [Qt versions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-project-qmake.html) and than add a [kit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html) (select the static version, the right compiler and debugger) and don't forget to name the kit so that you recognize it that is the static one (especially if you have many Qt versions on your system) and last step is to add the kit for your project (use *Projects* -> *Add Kits*)